# Xcode / iOS Delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

If I have a view controller which implements two protocols:

`@interface CustomerOperationsViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate`>

Is there any easy way to create the required callbacks for the protocols?  Maybe an Xcode shortcut for implement methods?  I'm going to the documentation each time for this.

Related, is it possible to put the delegate into a different file than the file owner?  I don't see how to drag from the UI element to a class other than the file owner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to XCode, one of the more frustrating IDEs out there. There isn't a particularly straightforward way to pre-populate callbacks, although they should come through in CodeSense. You could copy/paste from the header files, but you'll still need to manually edit some stuff.

As to your second question: yes - your delegate doesn't have to be the file owner, but normally if you were setting it to something else you'd do it programatically rather than via IB. Where/what did you want your delegate to be? Another view controller, or something different?

Comment: I was thinking it would be cleaner in a seperate file similar to the ApplicationDelegate.  However, I guess this isn't best practice as you then don't have easy access to the other outlets etc configured in the view controller.  e.g. I;m best to just put delegates on the view controller?

Comment: And yes, I'm missing IntelliJ :)

Comment: It's normally best to put the delegates in the view controller, see Apple's template UITableViewController file. But you certainly could use another class or object, it's just not something I've done regularly - and when I have, I didn't use IB to set the delegate property. If you're being strictly MVC, you'd put the delegate in a view controller: eg, in the case of UIPickerView: the PickerView itself is in your *view*, and the control over what's displayed in that picker goes in your *controller* (with the data going in the *model*, which for a pickerview may not be a separate class).

Comment: I'm with you on the missing IntelliJ xcode is pretty bad at just about everything. The good news is Xcode 4 does look promising.

Answer (score 4):

Just Command-Click on the delegate method and it will show you the delegate's header, so you don't need to browse the internet (e.g. Apple's Developer Site) for the appropriate docs. Also, in my implementation files I usually write code like this whenever I implement a delegate:

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // implementation here ...
}

#pragma mark - UITableVieWDataSource

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // implementation here ...
}
```

By Command-Clicking on the pragma mark text (UITableViewDelegate / UITableViewDataSource), the delegate header will be shown as well, less navigation to the header file of the current class to Command-Click the protocol. Just copy and paste the methods you need from the delegate's header.

Finally what's also useful is just start typing in Xcode (any implementation file that conforms to the protocol you want to autocomplete) ...

```
- tableView
```

and press escape. The tableView delegate methods will pop-up and you can select the one you want with tab, it will autocomplete. Same is true for delegates of other objects.

[image: Example]